# The following files are over 100mb. - Github

Tags: xcode, github

I'm trying to upload my app to gitHub, which are a pretty small application tbh. But whenever I tries to push it I'm getting the error message:

[image: Firebase]

And the application is not really big.

Note!

I am caching images in the application which I think might be one of the problems. Should I ever delete the cache in the app? Every time I open the application all the images loads and then saves in the cache. If I exit the app (not terminating) the application is still using the same cache if I'm returning back. But if I terminate the app and re-enters it, the image will download once again and save in cache.

Is there any other way to do this? Prevent loading and saving the images in the cache again? Should I ever clear the image cache? If so, when?

I've no idea what I can do to upload this version to gitHub, since somehow its over 100mb and the application should not even be close to that big.

I tried to delete the derviedData file, and re-built the application and ran it again. Afterwards I tried to push it to gitHub without any success.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not use `Git LFS` like the message suggests?

Comment: @nopassport1 Because I'm afraid the application is not really this size. So feels like a bad practice to upload a WAY to big file to GitHub. I'm not really sure If I've done right regarding to the image caching etc. Like, idk if I should delete the image cache if app is terminated etc, etc. Or If there is any other way to save the image caching ALL time, instead of loading it every time the app is running.

So you prefer Git LFS?

Comment: In that case you might want to update your question body/ title. The title suggests you want to get around the issue of uploading large files to GitHub, rather than _'how to cache images appropriately'_. If you're looking for a caching solution, I suggest a quick google search for just that. I found multiple up-to-date video tutorials on this topic. At the moment, `What can I do to fix this issue?` - would be to use `Git LFS` and you won't see the message anymore

Comment: @nopassport1 Ah sorry for misunderstanding. I'm asking if thats a bad way to upload a file which seems to be over 100mb (which I think is because of the image caching) when the app is not even close to be that big. I hope you understand. :) And thanks for your effort. :)

Comment: What file exactly are you trying to upload? Did you archive the file into an ipa file? Otherwise whatever you put on Github will be mostly useless.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I've gitHub desktop on my MacBook, and clicked on "Repositories" -> "Add local repository" and finally clicked on the map of the app.

Comment: The warning message popup suggests the file 'too large for GitHub' is one of your builds. Do you need to store this on GitHub? The popular `.gitignore` file for Xcode seems to ignore any `DerivedData` and `build` folders. https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore I don't know your usecase but you can just build the project yourself if you have the essential swift sourcecode and project files from GitHub. Which makes uploading of the `DerivedData/` & `build` folders redundant

Comment: DerivedData and anything under it should not be part of your git repository since it contains build (binary) data. Constrict your repository to contain only source code, project files etc